# Problema con CORS usando Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión usando ajax a la URL **http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations**. Primero he usado **POSTMAN** para hacer un test de la conexión y me ha devuelto los datos correctamente.

Seguidamente, en POSTMAN hay una opción para generar el código en Javascript con Ajax

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "0f26b085-397b-40ef-a3b9-2a82a54721f8,62cdc073-cc9d-4b0b-846d-a1264fa90c2f",
    "Host": "wservice.viabicing.cat",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Este código que genera, saltan errores de CORS y de Cabaceras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que el error proviene de `jquery` pero teoricamente el CDN es el correcto `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

He modificado el código para ver si de alguna forma termina funcionando, pero nada

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations",
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType":"jsonp",
    // "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "headers": {
        // "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        // "Postman-Token": "2e19325b-518f-424e-aedf-d30aaa4f6fff,359a4d2e-a610-4b72-b6f9-d493fc9ca556",
        // "Host": "wservice.viabicing.cat",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        // "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
     }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Pero me salta este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea?

Comment: El endpoint tu lo hiciste? La política del CORS del servidor está rechazando toda petición que el host sea `localhost`

Comment: ¿Pero si entiendes el mensaje de error? Ahí te está diciendo que intentas cargar recursos de un origen diferente (la URL de viabicing) al dominio del servidor (localhost) donde corres el código. Revisa el enlace que comparte @JackNavaRow sobre CORS.